# Selecting one column of dataframe as index and one column as value for a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV (pokemon.csv) with multiple columns like `name`, `type1`, `type2`, `pokedex`, etc.
I want to load the csv as a `dataframe` and then get one pandas `series` out of it.
I want to give `name` column as index and `type1` column as value, so I am doing this:

```
import pandas as pd
indexed_series = pd.read_csv('./pokemon.csv', index_col = 'name',  usecols = ['type1']).squeeze()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Index name invalid
```

What am I missing?

Comment: More info on the contents of your csv would be needed to be sure, but my guess would be that you are looking for: `pd.read_csv('./pokemon.csv', index_col = 'name',  usecols = ['name', 'type1']).squeeze()`. I.e., you need to include `name` in the list passed to `usecols` as well.

Comment: oh wow! that solved it @ouroboros1! the `name` column had to be added in the `usecols` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the situation. You need to specify 'name' in the usecols list as well. Then, you can refer to 'name' as an index column and the results will be a data frame with one column (type 1) and index based on the name.

```
test_df = pd.read_csv("./pokemon.csv", index_col='name', usecols=['name', 'type1'])

# it has only one column - name is index
print(len(test_df.columns))  # 1 - type1 is the only column

# still a dataframe
print(type(test_df))  # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

# if you want the Series
print(type(test_df.type1))  # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I got the same solution from the comments on my question too!